# Android: Animate a View to move up based on value

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview, android-animation

I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `AppBarLayout` and I have computed the percentage of how much the user scrolls and perform certain animations by this code:

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

            float totalScrollRange = Math.abs(appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange());
            float offset = Math.abs(verticalOffset);
            float scrollOffsetPercentageReverse;
            float scrollOffsetPercentage;
            float percentage;

            if (offset > 0) {
                percentage = (offset / totalScrollRange) * 100;
            } else {
                percentage = 0;
            }

            int reverse = 100 - (int) percentage; // 100 = 0,
            if (reverse > 0) {
                scrollOffsetPercentageReverse = 255.0f * (reverse / 100.0f);
                scrollOffsetPercentage = 255 * (percentage / 100);

                mBookCoverThumb.setImageAlpha((int) scrollOffsetPercentageReverse);

            }

            float scalePercentage = reverse / 100.0f;

            mBookCoverThumb.setScaleX(scalePercentage);
            mBookCoverThumb.setScaleY(scalePercentage);

        }
    });
```

As you can see, I have performed `Scale` and `Alpha` animations on `mBookCoverThumb`. However, I want it also to animate moving up based on the percentage value that I have, and vice versa wherein it goes back to its original place. I have tried `view.animate().translationY(percentage)` and `view.setTranslateY(percentage)` but I don't think I am doing it right. Any suggestions?

Here is the current behavior:

[image]

The `mBookCover` is anchored to my `AppBarLayout` that's why it moves a bit up when I scroll but I believe the layout constraints are preventing it from scrolling further up.